# Рваный/ступенчатый массив не получается реализовать

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, символы

Нужно перевести строку A в массив строк B состоящий из слов строки A, и затем, разбить этот массив строк B на двумерный массив, только уже из символов. На просторах "so" наткнулся на рваный/ступенчатый массив, только реализовать эту вещь здесь не получается. Прошу помощи, ибо представить эту конструкцию становится сложно. 
Строка A берется из textBox_input.Text

```
String[] s; //Сплитенный массив строк из слов
....
s  = textBox_input.Text.Split(' ',',');
        Char[][] cs = new Char [s.Length][];

        for (int j=0;j<s.Length;j++)
            for (int i=0;i<cs[j].Length;i++)
                cs[j] = s[i].ToCharArray();
```

Comment: А что, пол-вашему, делает выражение `s[i].ToCharArray();`?

Comment: cs[j] это (я надеюсь так описал) один из массивов для знаков, и его хочу заполнить массивом знаков, получившимся из слова в s[i] посредством ToCharArray(), который выдает массив знаков из слова.

Comment: Это уже лучше. То есть внешний цикл, понятно, по словам. А по каким элементам внутренний цикл?

Comment: @VladD хотелось бы чтобы по массивам в массиве прыгал и писал туда символы. Не знаю на чем горю - с одной стороны, с того что cs[j].Length не существует, а по другому задать не придумал как - написал циклы в порыве, а теперь не могу вникнуть - зачем там что. Точнее -понимаю, но так, как я это понимаю - это не работает.

Comment: Вы слишком сложно думаете. `s[j].ToArray()` возвращает вам что? Массив символов. Ну так что с этим массивом надо сделать?

Comment: записать в массив строк или по факту- в массив массивов - рваный массив символов. Но кажется я исправил цикл, сейчас остается это дело вывести.

Comment: Вы опят мыслите как-то сложно. У вас `cs[j]` должно быть массивом символов слова `s[j]`. А что производит `s[j].ToArray()`?

Comment: @VladD ` s  = textBox_input.Text.Split(' ', ',',',');
Char[][] cs = new Char [s.Length][];
for (int j=0;j<s.Length;j++)
 for (int i=0;i< s[j].ToCharArray().Length;i++)
cs[j] = s[j].ToCharArray();`   вот эта вещь делает то, что я и задумал.

Comment: @vl s[j].ToArray() представляет СТРОКУ номер j  из массива s в массив символов.

Comment: Окей, то есть это массив нужных символов, как раз тот, который должен быть в ступенчатом массиве на `j`-ом месте, правильно?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = textBox_input.Text.Split(' ', ',',','); 
Char[][] cs = new Char [s.Length][]; 
for (int j=0;j<s.Length;j++) 
    for (int i=0;i< s[j].ToCharArray().Length;i++) 
        cs[j] = s[j].ToCharArray();
```

В таком представлении код делает то, что мне нужно.

Comment: А теперь посмотрите, внутренний цикл несколько раз делает одно и тоже, видите? Код внутри цикла не зависит от `i`.

Comment: Хуже того, как оказалось, внутренний цикл ещё и вредит: при `s[j].ToCharArray().Length == 0` цикл вовсе не инициализирует `cs[j]`.